# Error when running jupyter notebook with Miniconda on Windows 10 in 2022

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Whatever I try any of the following

```
jupyter notebook
juputer-notebook.exe
python -m notebook
```

I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\notebook\__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from notebook import notebookapp as app
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 79, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._version import __version__, version_info
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\nbformat\_version.py", line 27, in <module>
    _version_fields = _version_regex.match(__version__).groupdict()  # type:ignore
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I have `conda 4.14.0` and `jupyter --version` returns

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 7.33.0
ipykernel        : 6.16.0
ipywidgets       : 8.0.2
jupyter_client   : 7.3.5
jupyter_core     : 4.11.1
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\Scripts\jupyter-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 202, in main
    mod = __import__(package)
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\nbclient\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import NotebookClient, execute  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\nbclient\client.py", line 15, in <module>
    from nbformat import NotebookNode
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._version import __version__, version_info
  File "C:\Users\yt75534\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\nbformat\_version.py", line 27, in <module>
    _version_fields = _version_regex.match(__version__).groupdict()  # type:ignore
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I see that I don't have `jupyter_server` installed (well, I guess I just need a client) and `jupyterlab` but I don't think that is a problem, or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you try installing notebook using conda (`conda install notebook`) in your current environment and then try `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: `# All requested packages already installed.` and it keeps in not working.

Comment: I am not sure what's causing the error. But may be you can create a new environment in conda and install jupyter lab in it and run jupyter notebook/lab inside the new environment?

Comment: It worked and I used `conda install ipython=8.5.0` on the old virtual environment getting tons of conflicts: https://ibb.co/Y7LNPVs I solved by removing and re-creating the virtual environment through an `environment.yml`. Now everything works.

Comment: Awesome!! May be you want to write that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by removing and re-creating the virtual environment through an `environment.yml`

```
conda deactivate
conda env remove --name myenv
conda create -f environment.yml
conda activate myenv
```

The file `environment.yml` contains information such as environment name, package list etc.

See `conda` documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command in base environment:

```
conda uninstall jupyter_core nbformat nbconvert notebook
```

It worked for me.