# Jupyter Notebook Unable to Launch

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My jupyter was running fine this morning and then I get the below error when I try launching it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in from notebook.notebookapp import main

File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 80, in 
from .services.x.manager import ContentsManager

File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in 
from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError

File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 12, in 
from ._version import __version__, version_info

File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\_version.py", line 27, in 
_version_fields = _version_regex.match(__version__).groupdict() # type:ignore

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Any tips on how to trouble shoot this?

Comment: What you are seeing looks a lot like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74012588/8508004). Perhaps those solutions will help?